# Include `self` in CocoaLumberjack log

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoalumberjack

What is the best way to include `self` in each log message in [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack)?

What I tried:

- Implementing the `DDLogFormatter` protocol - the caller of the log message is not available in the `formatLogMessage:` method.
- `#define`ing something like:

  `#define LogInfo(frmt, ...) DDLogInfo(([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", self, frmt]), ##__VA_ARGS__)` (note the extra `()` around the `[NSString ...]` - thanks [hamstergene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544621/hamstergene)

  which will create a problem whenever I want to reference `self` weakly, e.g. calling `LogInfo` inside a block - including `self` would potentially cause memory problems.

What am I missing? Any other better logging library?

Comment: The second should work if you put an extra `()` around `[...]`.

Comment: That works, can you explain why the extra `()` helped?

Comment: C preprocessor does not recognize `[]` as brackets, the commas inside them confuse it to think it's three separate macro arguments.

Comment: Be very careful about using that macro within blocks -- that can create a hidden strong reference to self, which in some situations can create a retain loop.  When I've done something like this, I make a second logging macro which takes an object argument explicitly, so you can pass in a weakSelf if necessary.  With a custom macro, you might be able to pass the object as the tag, and a special context value to know it's the logging object, if you want to do something special in the formatter.